# Spyder consumes massive bandwidth whenever it is open on windows 10

Tags: python, connection, spyder, lag

Whenever I have Spyder opened on windows 10, it consumes heavy bandwidth. For example, if I have Spyder opened while having a Skype conversation, the connection becomes really laggy. This goes for all applications, really.

I have tried searching previous posts regarding this issue, but haven't found a solution.

I have noticed that each time I open Spyder, several pythonw.exe processes are created - see picture below:

[image]

Can anyone help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder developer here*) This is a known issue, and it doesn't have to do with consuming a lot of bandwidth as with doing of lot ping's to the network.

Unfortunately, we don't know how to fix it, sorry.